# How important are higher degrees in a tech industry?

Tags: hiring-process, tech-industry, education

How important are higher degrees in a tech industry? Asides the obvious cases of very specialised companies that perform their own high tech research, does having different levels of higher education benefit the applicant (comparing for example, someone that has a collage degree, to BSc, MSc, D.Sc)?

Comment: This questions is to broad to be constructive.  You could narrow it down to a specific field, and what application of the degree you are talking about, ie finding a job, performing at a job, getting promoted etc.  Also the value of a AAS, BS, MS, and PhD are vary different as well.  I could easily ask 20 versions of this question where the answer is different.

Comment: I agree that the question is too broad. One way of finding out the approximate answer for a specific industry and area would be to look at job postings - some fields will have a lot of offers that require a MSc, some will have few of those and many that require "a BSc and 2-4 years of experience, or an MSc", i.e. the MSc only counts for as much as equivalent length of work experience.

Comment: Simple Answer: Very Important!

Comment: Unless you're a client-side engineer in which case it's a lot less important than what you've learned from experience/self-study. Hence the overly broad issue.

Comment: Not sure - many of the best programmers I have known have had little to no formal training in programming.  It's something they did because they wanted to, and they fell into the jobs because they had the right skills at the right time.  On the other hand I have known a few PhD graduates who were up to the same level as the self-starters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that higher education never hurts, but beyond that, it's hard to say how important it is. Really depends on what you're after in your career. It can be absolutely critical, it can be less important, but I'm not sure how to quantify it without applying it to something more specific.